# Dynamic length of SQL args

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO home_title VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

However, the length of arguments is 57. How would I dynamically create the (%s, %s, ...) based on multiplying by 57?

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the strings directly? Must be quicker and easier than to use formating-syntax, no? http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

Comment: @claj: sorry? You don't use string formatting for SQL parameters, lest you want to open yourself to a SQL attack. The `%s` placeholders are not used for string formatting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate them with:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO home_title VALUES ({})'.format(', '.join(['%s'] * 57))
```

This interpolates 57 `'%s'` strings joined together with a comma and space.

Demo with a lower argument count:

```
>>> 'INSERT INTO home_title VALUES ({})'.format(', '.join(['%s'] * 5))
'INSERT INTO home_title VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

Comment: + Add an extra parenthesis at the end

Comment: @user1436531: mea culpa, fixed.

Comment: It may be worth explaining why this is safe, because I've seen some novices not get it: You _are_ generating a SQL string dynamically, which is usually bad. But you're not involving any user data in that dynamic string generation; all you're putting in are literal `%s` placeholders. So, there's no way for anyone to do SQL injection here. (They can't change your literals—or, if they could, they could just write any SQL they wanted anyway.)

Comment: @abarnert: I was assuming the OP already knew about using SQL parameters, supported by the fact they didn't use `'%s'` placeholders (*with* quotes).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, but I've had at least two people, when faced with code like this, say, "But I thought it was never safe to build SQL strings dynamically". It's not that they didn't know how to use placeholders—they wouldn't have even asked the question if they didn't—but that they didn't really understand why it's not (generally) safe to build SQL strings dynamically, so therefore didn't understand why it _is_ safe here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
", ".join(["%s"] * 57)
```